# Thread Safety With Parallel Operations

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, thread-safety

Before I start, I should mention that I feel like I've got the wrong end of the stick here. But here we go anyway:

Imagine we have the following class:

```
public class SomeObject {
    public int SomeInt;
    private SomeObject anotherObject;

    public void DoStuff() {
        if (SomeCondition()) anotherObject.SomeInt += 1;
    }
}
```

Now, imagine that we have a collection of these `SomeObject`s:

```
IList<SomeObject> allObjects = new List<SomeObject>(1000);
// ... Pretend the list is populated with 1000 SomeObjects here
```

Let's say I call `DoStuff()` on each one, like so:

```
foreach (var @object in allObjects) @object.DoStuff();
```

All is good so far.
Now, let's assume that the order in which the objects have their `DoStuff()` called is not important. Assume that `SomeCondition()` is computationally expensive, perhaps. I could utilize all four cores on my machine (and potentially get a performance gain) with:

```
Parallel.For(0, 1000, i => allObjects[i].DoStuff());
```

Now, ignoring any issues with atomicity of variable access, I don't care whilst I am in the loop whether or not any given `SomeObject` sees an outdated version of `anotherObject` or `SomeInt`.* However, once the loop is done, I want to make sure that my main worker thread (i.e. the one that called Parallel.For) DOES see everything up-to-date.

Is there a guarantee of this (e.g. some sort of memory barrier?) with using Parallel.For? Or do I need to make some sort of guarantee myself? Or is there no way to make this guarantee?

Finally, if I call `Parallel.For(...)` again in the same way just after, will all worker threads be working with the new, up-to-date values for everything?

---

(*) The implementers of `DoStuff()` would be wrong to make assumptions about the order of processing anyway, right?

Comment: the Parallel.For it returns synchronously in the calling thread? so For and Parallel.For shoud retrun the same result in your example!

Comment: Yes, but will all modifications made on separate threads be visible in the calling thread?

Comment: Yes, but when the anotherObject is shared between SomeObject instances, it needs to be **threadsafe**. The Parallel.For will return until all items are done. They are executed the same as normal For, only parallel, but the order could be screwed.

Comment: Jeroen, I only want that thread safety after the parallel.for has finished. I don't care about it whilst parallel.for is running (because I couldn't guarantee the order those elements are touched anyway). I just want to make sure that everything is up to date once my for loop has ended.

Comment: After the Parallel.For all multithread stuff is done, so after the Parallel.For you're free to do what you want. Because the Parallel.For is blocking.

Comment: Yep, but I'm asking about the visible state of shared data after it's done.

Answer (score 1):

```
        var locker = new object();
        var total = 0.0;
        Parallel.For(1, 10000000,
        i => { lock (locker) total += (i + 1); });
        Console.WriteLine("WithLocker" + total);

        var total2 = 0.0;
        Parallel.For(1, 10000000,
        i => total2 += (i + 1));
        Console.WriteLine("WithoutLocker" + total2);
        Console.ReadKey();

        // WithLocker 50000004999999
        // WithoutLocker 28861729333278
```

I have made for you two example one with locker and one without look to the result!

Comment: This is interesting. It means that Parallel.For is basically only useful for code that's already thread-safe... Damn.

Comment: Although... This might be due to the non-atomicity of +=. I'd be interested to see the result with an atomic operation.

Comment: This shows that `+=` is not atomic and so calling it from multiple threads at the same time is not thread-safe. But it doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: Interlocked.Increment would be much more efficient here anyways. Locks are generally expensive, effectively this is a sequential implementation as each += operation is inside a lock so only one can execute at any one time.

Answer (score 1):

There are  two issues here.

> However, once the loop is done, I want to make sure that my main worker thread (i.e. the one that called Parallel.For) DOES see everything up-to-date.

To answer your question. Yes, once your `Parallel.For` has completed all the calls to `DoStuff` will have completed and your array will not see any more updates.

> Now, ignoring any issues with atomicity of variable access, I don't care whilst I am in the loop whether or not any given SomeObject sees an outdated version of anotherObject or SomeInt.*

I really doubt that you don't care about this if you want a correct answer. Bassam's answer addresses the potential data races in your code. If one thread is running `DoSomething` and this writes to another index in the array which is simultaneously being read by another thread then you will see nondeterministic results. Locking can solve this (as shown above) but at the expense of performance. Locking on every thread for every update effectively serializes your work. I suspect that Bassam's lock example actually runs no faster and possibly slower that the non-locking one, although it does produce the correct answer.

If `SomeObject::anotherObject` refers to anything other than `this` you have a potential race condition. Consider the case where `anotherObject` refers to the element in the array adjacent to the current object. What happens when these run concurrently? One thread's code will be trying to read an instance of `SomeObject` while another thread writes to it. The write **not** guaranteed to happen atomically, your read my return an object in a half written state.

This depends a bit on what is being updated in SomeObject and how it's being updated. For example if all you are doing is incrementing an single integer value you could use [Interlocked Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbhbke0y.aspx) to increment the value in a thread safe way or use critical sections or locks to ensure that your `SomeObject` is actually thread safe. Adding synchronization operations usually impacts performance so if possible I would recommend looking for an approach that does not require adding synchronization.

You can fix this in one of two ways.

1) If each instance of `anotherObject` in the array is guaranteed to be only updated once by one call to `allObjects[i].DoStuff()` then you can modify your code to have an input and output array. This prevents any race conditions as reads and writes no longer conflict. It means you need two copies of your array and they both need to be initialized.

2) If you are updating array items multiple times, or having two arrays of `SomeObject` is not an option and `SomeCondition()` is the only computationally expensive part of your method then you could parallelize this and then update the array sequentially.

```
IList<bool> allConditions = new List<bool>(1000);
Parallel.For(0, 1000, i => SomeCondition(i)) // Write allConditions not allObjects
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) { @object.DoStuff(allConditions[i]); }
```

So your observation:

> This is interesting. It means that Parallel.For is basically only useful for code that's already thread-safe... Damn

Is not entirely correct. The code within your `Parallel.For` must either be thread safe or not access data and resources in a non-thread safe way. In other words it doesn't have to lock if you can rearrange your code to guarantee that there are no race conditions (or deadlocks) because none of the threads write the same data or will read data that another thread may be writing to. Note that concurrent reads are OK.

Comment: Hey Ade, thanks for the answer! What I'm trying to achieve is a 'game loop' where all the SomeObjects are updated x times a second. I don't care if, *during* any update, the state of some of the code is stale according to any given SomeObject. Because they would be executed in an arbitrary order anyway. I *do* want each update to be fully 'realised' before the next one begins however... Does that make sense?

Comment: And, so, if I understand your comments... Assuming that any given write is atomic, the worst that could happen is that a SomeObject sees another SomeObject in the state it was in before any writes; even if those writes really have happened?